# Compacting too many if clauses using Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming

I have written following code block in Java:

```
public mainFunction() {

...

if (!functionA(data1, data2)) {
  return new Left<>(Reason.INVALID_RULE);
}

if (!functionB(data1, data2)) {
  return new Left<>(FAILURE.INVALID_ID);
}

 ...there are a few if clauses like above...
}


private boolean functionA(Data1 data1, Data2 data2) {
    if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(data1.getAttr1)) {
       data2.setAttr1(data1.getAttr1);
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean functionA(Data1 data1, Data2 data2) {
    try{
       data2.setAttr1(Attr2Enum.fromValue(data1.getAttr1));
       return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    return false;
    }
}
```

Now, my question is can I compact them using Java8?

Comment: Different functions, different return values, I'm not sure we can make your code any more concise.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen return values and arguments are the same actually in all functions called from if clauses in mainFunction().

Comment: The return values are different.  (If they were the same, you wouldn't need to call the 2nd, 3rd, etc function.).  But I agree with Tim that there doesn't look like there is any scope for making this more concise.

Comment: Why would you not consider Chain of responsibility for this Design?

Comment: I would point out that `catch (Exception e) { return false; }` is a really bad idea.  It is going to *hide* bugs.

Comment: @AnupamAlok - I think it is unlikely to make the code more concise ... overall.  But if you think it would help, write an Answer, showing how to applying CoR to the OP's example.  (So that we can >>see<< if it is more concise.)

Comment: Don’t call actions that modify the incoming objects “function”. Don’t use anti-patterns like `catch(Exception e) { return false; }`. If you clean up your code, the problem may already disappear.

Comment: It Completely depends on real use case. Give me a accurate situation and I will try to give you the most compact code as possible

Answer (score 0):

There can me multiple ways to do it.
I tried to create a Validator interface which can do this kind of validation chaining.
Although its not a perfect solution but it may give you an idea to start with. Its a much generic solution (can be more generic with ? super and ? extends - you can try on your own)

Code:

```
package pecs;

import javafx.util.Pair;

public class Chaining {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Validation<Integer, String, Message> validation = (a, b, c) -> {
            return new Pair(a > 30, new Message("a should not be greater than 30"));
        };
        Validation<Integer, String, Message> validation2 = (a, b, c) -> {
            return new Pair(a > 20, new Message("a should not be greater than 20"));
        };
        Validation<Integer, String, Message> validation3 = (a, b, c) -> {
            return new Pair(a > 10, new Message("a should not be greater than 10"));
        };
        Validation<Integer, String, Message> validation4 = (a, b, c) -> {
            return new Pair(a > 5, new Message("a should not be greater than 5"));
        };

        //One way to call
        Validation<Integer, String, Message> validator = validation
                .and(validation2)
                .and(validation3)
                .and(validation4);

        System.out.println(validator.validate(4, "A00", 0));
        System.out.println(validator.validate(9, "A00", 0));
        System.out.println(validator.validate(11, "A00", 0));
        System.out.println(validator.validate(21, "A00", 0));
        System.out.println(validator.validate(31, "A00", 0));

        //Another way to call
        Pair<Boolean, Message> pair = validation
                .and(validation2)
                .and(validation3)
                .and(validation4)
                .validate(4, "String", 0);
        if(pair.getKey() == false) {
            System.out.println("All Validation successful");
        } else {
            System.out.println(pair);
        }

    }
}
```

The validator interface used in the code:

```
package pecs;

import javafx.util.Pair;
import java.util.Objects;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface Validation<A, B, C> {
    Pair<Boolean, C> validate(A a, B b, int count);

    default Validation<A, B, C> and(Validation<A, B, C> other) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(other);
        return (a, b, c) -> {
//            System.out.println("c=" + c);
            Pair<Boolean, C> validate = validate(a, b, c+1);
            if (validate.getKey() == true) {
                return validate;
            } else {
                //Termination condition.
                if(c == 0) {
                    Pair<Boolean, C> pair = other.validate(a, b, c);
                    if(pair.getKey() == false) {
                        return new Pair<>(false, null);
                    } else {
                        return pair;
                    }
                } else {
                    return other.validate(a, b, c);
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Please have a look and suggest if any improvements.
There are many other ways to do validation. Say for example, check this link:
https://dzone.com/articles/server-side-validator-using-functional-interfaces

Comment: Author never mentioned using JavaFX, so please, don't make them import JavaFX as it can lead to several issues.

Comment: Yes right, custom pair class can be created

Comment: OK ... so in the OP's actual example, it looks like you would have replace N `if` statements with code that makes N `Validation` objects. Plus a bunch of extra boilerplate to unpick the resulting pairs. I don't see how that is an actual improvement ... unless the `Validation` objects are being used in lots of places. (And even then ... there is a different problem ... which is having the declarations of the `Validation` objects separated from their use(s).)

Comment: @StephenC: Those validation objects can be reused and avoid code duplicacy. Removing and adding validation is easy. There are multiple such advantages. Boilerplate is everywhere, just that its hidden in libraries. Try using any existing validator implementation if you want to avoid boilerplate. Its code once and leave.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a map of the type `Map<BiPredicate<Data1, Data2>, Left<?>>` using the `Map.of` function, where the predicates are aligned to the corresponding results, and then stream over the `entrySet` of the map.

Something like:

```
Map.<BiPredicate<Data1, Data2>of( (data1,data2)->{return
!functionA(data1, data2)},  new Left<>(Reason.INVALID_RULE))
```

etc..., then

```
.entrySet().stream()
```

then `.map` or `.forEach` over the entries.